# ¿Qué quiere decir que una revisión tenga el texto "Edición eliminada durante el período de gracia"?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

En la [revisión de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/228360/revisions) encuentro el siguiente texto:

> [Edición eliminada durante el período de gracia]

Realmente, no sé si este texto lo agregó el OP o es un texto pre-determinado de la revisión.

*Captura de pantalla:*

> [image: Captura de pantalla - revisión]

De ser el caso *(en que sea un texto pre-determinado)*, ¿qué significa este texto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es una [funcionalidad implementada en 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564/209901) con la que se indica aquellas revisiones que se realizaron en una publicación que terminaron siendo exactamente la misma que la edición anterior a esa publicación.

Me explico:

1. Ves una publicación y te pones a editarla.
2. Esos cambios generan una línea de edición en el historial de la publicación.
3. Tras un rato, pero siempre dentro de los 5 minutos de período de gracia, decides cambiar más cosas, con la mala pata que acabas dejando la publicación igual que estaba antes de empezar todo el proceso en el punto 1.
4. Resulta que la edición reportada en el punto 2. consiste en nada, por lo que el sistema lo resume en "[Edición eliminada durante el período de gracia]" porque es básicamente lo que pasó: durante el período de gracia se hicieron ediciones que finalmente se eliminaron.

---

Ejemplo paso a paso en esta misma respuesta:

1. Edito para añadir un texto cualquiera ("holaholahola"):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En el [historial de revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3858/revisions) vemos que se reporta así:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Posteriormente elimino este texto nuevo, dejando la publicación como estaba en la primera revisión:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vemos, a partir de este momento aparece la versión definitiva, que es la que se ve si aprietas en "editada hace..."

> [Edición eliminada durante el período de gracia]